# How To Set A Required Field On All Devices?

Tags: html, forms, form-submit, requiredfieldvalidator

I have set a 'required' field for the following fields in my HTML5 website:

```
    <td><p><label>Full Name:<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required></td>
    <p><label>Phone #:<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" required>
```

On the computer, laptop, etc. the required field works. The person cannot hit submit without putting in these fields.

However, on any mobile device the 'required' code does not seem to work. I wanted to know if there is another code I can use to work on mobile devices.

Any help, tips, advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 'required' form attribute is unfortunately not available in many mobile browsers.

Rerefernce: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

You'd need to use a JavaScript polyfill such as this:
http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/#